# Mango seedling leaf's mosaic pattern - if it is a cause for concern or not?

Tags: diseases, indoors, mango

At the time I am trying to understand if mosaic leaf pattern in my young mango seedling is a symptom or not but can't find something similar in appearance. My young mango plant now is 4 months old. It is Kent variety which grew up from a seed of store bought fruit in a pot indoors. At the planting time seed was remarkable for black mold lesions. It was planted in peat (pH 5,5 - 6,5) plus a bit of perlite mix, grew in room temperature (23 - 25 C), with 3 - 4 hours of direct sunlight per day and had approximately 1 watering per 7 to 8 days (to the point when the soil dried up to 5 cm from above) and firstly the things went just ok and it was fine. After a three months or so one day I surprisingly discovered, that older leaves look a bit of mosaic through the light but otherwise plant was good. Later I found out that underside of the leaves covered with some sticky stuff along the veins, which was removed with water and soft cloth and today, which is a week o so later, I saw small (2 - 3 mm) black spots on the oldest leave with increasing of that patchy mosaic pattern. It's underside was covered with similar sticky substance and more over, at the first time there was afids - as well as on the underside of the other leaves, stem and potting soil surface. The leave was removed because of the black spot disease (I'm not sure if it is anthracnose, but afraid of it), all the leaves was washed and rubbed a bit with water and soft cloth once again till I couldn't find any sticky afid's stuff underneath and azoxistrobin (1 ml of 250 g/l suspension per 1 l of water) was used because of some fungal infection concern. But after all, mosaic looking leaves remain, so now there are some questions. 1) Is it some sap sucking insects the cause and some treatment required (at first, probably, soap+oil+water or something else)? 2) Is it any systemic fungal infection and some systemic fungicide needed? 3) Is it some nutritional deficiency because of peat? 4) or is it just something unrelated (which is obviously the less likely) to other problems?

Need to say, that in that seedling some stem luxation appeared progressively, so I'm concerned about some fungal root rot or something like that. But for now it looks quite good.

(for some reason I can't attach a picture)

Thanks a lot!

[image: overall plant view]

[image: the removed leave with a black spots]

Comment: You should try to attach a photo...if you can't do it in your post, try to do it in the comment section...It will help the community to visually understand the condition..

Comment: What kind of mosaic pattern is it? Is it blocky, or cirlces? Are the shapes necrotic or not? Aphids can spread viruses and stuff, as can many other pests.

Comment: Actually I attached a couple of pictures. Mosaic pattern looks more circular with no necrotic margins, especially in the case of new lesions and tends to conflux with time and black spots appear later in the center of this lesion, so for me it looks more like some fungal/bacterial black spot appears in context of viral disease or some nutritional deficiency but I m not sure